# concatenation of string within lists

Tags: haskell

I have to concat two string given as input into one singe string and put it in a list as output

```
type Language = [String]
cat :: Language -> Language -> Language
cat l1 l2  = 
    case l1 of 
    [""] -> l2
    (x:xs) -> case l2 of 
              [""] -> l1
              (y:ys) -> xs ++ ys
```

and the output should be:

```
["string1string2"]
```

any Idea in haskell?

Comment: I have many ideas. Here are two: This is severely underspecified. The degree and form of underspecification suggests it's an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Carl Language is what I defined as a list of string Language = [String]. I need to concat the Language1 and Language2.

Comment: How do you want your strings to be concatenated? For example given `["a", "b"]` and `["c", "d"]` should the result be `["ac", "bd"]` or else should the result be `["ac", "ad", "bc", "bd"]`?

Comment: @AaditMShah within the list there's just a single string has to be concatenated to the second one. given ["a"] and ["b"] the result would be ["ab"].

Comment: @mehdix_ So you're saying the problem has massive input domain constraints you didn't bother specifying, which are so severe that they completely negate the semantic content of the types in use? It *really* sounds like you're solving the wrong problem. Subverting the type system is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Given the invariant that every `[String]` has exactly one element the simplest solution is `(++) <$> ["a"] <*> ["b"]` which uses the `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` operators from `Control.Applicative`. You could also use a `ZipList`, but in my opinion lists are simpler to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Given your exact problem specification, it is solved by

```
concatWithinLists :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
concatWithinLists [x] [y] = [x ++ y]
```

This is bad in all kinds of ways. All of them stem from your insistence that you will only ever have lists of exactly length 1, completely missing the point of lists.

I strongly recommend reconsidering everything that led you to this issue. The real problem isn't here - it's somewhere higher up in your design. It will continue to be a problem as long as you lie to the type system about the contents of your data. You aren't working with `[String]`, you're working with `String` and have attached some noise for no benefit.

Comment: @mehidx_ It simple terms: if you expect your list to only have one element then do you really need to use a list? Simply declare `type Language = String`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you passing your strings through in a list? Doing so opens problems, like your code crashing should empty lists be given as an argument (with the exception of `cat [""] []`). Plus, your pattern matching is off: `xs ++ ys` becomes `[] ++ []` when singleton lists are passed as arguments. This is because `[x] = x:[]`. A simpler solution would be:

```
cat :: String -> String -> [String]
cat s1 s2 = [s1 ++ s2]
```